# Principles of forming epic poem titles from words

Tags: ancient-greek, suffixes, word-formation

Could someone point me to a reliable source towards how are the -ας/-ις/etc. suffixes are applied to form the titles of epic poems?

For example, why Ίλιον > Ἰλιάς but Ἀχιλλεύς > Ἀχιλληΐς, and how come Ὀδυσσεύς > weird Ὀδύσσεια?